# React Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop when key is provided and unique

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering several list items from an api:

```
{clientSurveys &&
        clientSurveys?.map(({ data }, index) => (
          <ListItem
            key={data?.SurveyID}
            component={Link}
            to={`survey/${data?.SurveyID}`}
            disablePadding
            sx={{ color: 'inherit' }}
          >
)}
```

As seen above, I am providing a key (which is the id of the survey in this case):

```
key={data?.SurveyID}
```

Why am I keep getting this warning?

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Comment: can you confirm you have a unique id for SurveyID? Are there not duplicate SurveyIDs?

Comment: @SevenSouls Totally looks like it should work to me. Any chance that either A) The SurveyID values are not unique, B) the Survey ID values are undefined or C) the warning is coming from another list altogether?

Comment: @PrinceSodhi I'm pretty sure they're all unique (I checked in the console)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why am I keep getting this warning?

The *optional chaining* (`?`) in your `key` value suggests that the `data` might be *undefined*, so there's a chance that a couple of your items are getting the same key with `undefined` value.

```
key={data?.SurveyID} // it may end up with "undefined" value
```

You have to secure this case when `data` is `undefined`.

Its also worthy to mention that using the *optional chaining* in the `key` value is rather an *anti pattern*, because the `key` should be static and unique. `data?.SurveyID` also suggests that it might change over time.

Comment: Fair point. But I probably shouldn't add an optional chaining here because I'm doing: `clientSurveys &&` which ensures that the values are not undefined.

Comment: @SevenSouls `clientSurveys &&` does not ensure you that the `data` is not undefined. It ensures you that `clientSurveys` **exists** and is not undefined.

Comment: Interesting I wasn't aware of the difference. Thanks!  How would you approach this? Actually, setting it to `Math.random()` fixed the warning. But I want to use the actual unique id from the database as the keys

Comment: @SevenSouls Just out of curiosity - did you try with `key={index}`? It's not a good habit either, but the warning just should be gone. However if it still persists - are you sure that the warning comes from this iteration?

Comment: It worked with `key={index}`!

Comment: @SevenSouls Great to hear. There are different opinions about using `index` as a key, in your case you are not sorting the values so theoretically it should work, but the good habit is to use some other kind of a unique, static key.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your help! How would you ensure that the api data is not undefined? Since using short circuiting `&&` isn't the way to go?

Comment: @SevenSouls Your usage of `&&` is absolutely correct. You are properly checking if `clientSurveys` exists and if it's not undefined. But if you would like to do something similar with the `data`, it would look like `.map(({ data }, index) => data?.SurveyID && <ListItem...` but then you have to be aware that the items with `SurveyID` as undefined will not be rendered. Also you could filter the array before rendering from every item that `SurveyID` is undefined. But its just a longer story...:)

Comment: Thank you!!! Adding `data?.SurveyID &&` worked and I'm able to use it as key now.